# Insert json_encode() array into javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

Hi i am getting json_encode() array from php using ajax and storing that into a variable. how can i insert that array into javascript function?.

```
c = (parseInt(e.attr("data-invoice-id")), {                                     
//insert that array here
                }),
```

it should look like this.

```
c = (parseInt(e.attr("data-invoice-id")), {                                     
                    invoice_id: {
                        invoice_number: "Some Value",
                        invoice_orderno: "Some Value",
                        invoice_date: "Some Value",
                        invoice_due_date: "Some Value",
                        invoice_from_company: "",
                        invoice_from_address_1: "",
                        invoice_from_address_2: "India",
                        invoice_to_company: "Some Value",
                        invoice_to_address_1: "2894 Bond Street",
                        invoice_to_address_2: "Providence, RI 02908",
                        invoice_total_value: "Some Value",
                        invoice_vat_value: "00.00",
                        invoice_device: "Some Value",
                        invoice_dproblem: "Some Value",
                        invoice_dserial: "Some Value",                            
                        invoice_payment_info: "Cash On Delivery<br/>(COD)",
                        invoice_payment_due: "14"
                    }
                }),
```

Please help, i am a beginner in javascript

Comment: `var foo = <?php echo json_encode($somearray); ?>; var myarr = ["data": foo];`

Comment: You asked same question yesterday and ignored requests to show more code context. Where is the ajax code? Also that structure shown doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the php json_encode array in a variable

```
var data=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

then just use `JSON.parse` to parse the array

```
    c = (parseInt(e.attr("data-invoice-id")), {                                     
          var obj = JSON.parse(data)  
           }),
```

you are done!